# PyQt4: Changing button icon on action

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm trying to change buttons icon on specific action. (Clicked, Disabled etc.)

So as an example lets take a button press, If i have a button:

```
btn = QtGui.QPushButton(" ", self)
btn.resize(100, 100)
btn.move(0, 0)
btn.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(""))
btn.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 100))
```

How can i change its icon when clicked? Do i need to make a clicked signal?

`btn.clicked.connect(self.some_function_that_shows_new_icon)`

If so, how can i make disabled signal or any other button condition available?

Example:

`btn.disabled.connect(self.some_function_that_shows_new_icon)`

(Signal that will detect if buttons disabled or not, One above doesn't work)

Comment: btn.clicked.connect(self.some_function_that_shows_new_icon)
 that's true. And second, You can basically rewrite. Also there is no such disabled.connect thing

Comment: and is there something simillar like that?, i've used qt designer once and saw those conditions on icons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`QIcons` can have multiple images for different *modes* and *states*.  You add multiple `QPixmap`s to the same `QIcon` and specify the mode and state for that image.

```
icon = QIcon()
icon.addPixmap(QPixmap('normal.png'))
icon.addPixmap(QPixmap('disabled.png'), QIcon.Disabled)
icon.addPixmap(QPixmap('clicking.png'), QIcon.Active)
icon.addPixmap(QPixmap('on.png'), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.On)
btn.setIcon(icon)
```

It depends on whether clicking the button is changing the state of the button (eg. toggling it on or off).  If you're using the button to toggle the state of something else, this won't work.